# How to send /Pass Message to Chrome Extension from Java Desktop Application(like Java Swing application)

Tags: java, swing, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I searched so many links in Stack over flow and Chrome Extension API am not getting any proper information for how to send message from Java desktop application to chrome extension.

but so many struggles I implemented Chrome Extension and set Executable jar file in host.bat file. jar file execution is over, then my Question is how to send message from java Applet(Swing) to chrome Extension. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled by "Native Messaging" but consider this;

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

> Native applications that support this feature must register a native
>   messaging host that knows how to communicate with the extension

Comment: Hi!! @aliminnet i already register with a native messaging host. Everything works fine,but my Question is how to pass message to Chrome extension from Java Swing application....

Comment: I have faced the same issue and decided to use Rest API to overcome this issue

Comment: Please Provide any links related to this task am unable to find any links.